# Хочу с чистого листа установить Visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Хочу с чистого листа установить Visual studio 2013 с удалением 2008-2015. первый раз это делаю, поэтому нет понятия. Помогите, плиииз, по пунктикам)) 64разрядная ос

Comment: Просто взять и установить.Скачать VS с офф сайта и установить, а если возникнуть проблемы то уже задать

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно что значит 2008-2015, у вас установлено 2 версии студии-2008 и 2015?
Удалить visual studio можно запустив установщик с вашей версией и вам будет предложено удалить или восстановить.Если нет установщика(его можно скачать), то можно попробовать удалить через диспетчер задач, но, возможно, останутся некоторые каталоги(их можно удалить вручную-они в документах  в папке с названием вашей версии студии).
ссылка для скачивания Visual Studio 2013 [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-RU/download/details.aspx?id=44921)